# How do I perform VLOOKUP or INDEX MATCH based on three different criteria?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[image]

I can't figure out the proper formula to lookup a value based on three different criteria. I want to fill out the summary table with data from the source table.

I tried using INDEX, MATCH and SUMPRODUCT but the value always returned "-" instead of the correct value. Not sure how to combine the formula together

Say I want to fill in the Summary Table D16 where PersonA matches for both tables, the data is for Quarter 2 and the data would match the type which is Expense. How do I do this?

Comment: What have you tried? [Googling your question returns myriad examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+do+I+perform+VLOOKUP+or+INDEX+MATCH+based+on+three+different+criteria).

Comment: Are the Persons unique per row in the data set?

Answer (score 2):

Use INDEX to return the correct row:

```
INDEX(B:G,MATCH(A16,A:A,0),0)
```

Then use SUMIFS to return the correct Column's Value in that range:

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX(B:G,MATCH(A16,A:A,0),0),$B$2:$G$2,$C16,$B$3:$G$3,D$15)
```

Put the above in D16, copy over and down.

Comment: nice!  I was running through some sort of aggregate sumproduct option.  Much better to avoid the array calc option. +1